# Appending bcolz columns with Blaze

Tags: python, hdf5, blaze

Let's first construct a `ctable`:

```
import pandas as pd
import blaze as bl

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(4), 'y': [2., 4., 2., 4.]})
bl.odo(df, 'test.bcolz')
```

Now suppose I wanna add a column called 'x_mod' to this table. I tried

```
test_table = bl.Data('test.bcolz')

def f(h):
    return h*3
test_table['x_mod'] = test_table['x'].apply(f, dshape='int64')
#Or, I think equivalently:
#test_table['x_mod'] = test_table['x']*3
```

But it gives

```
TypeError: 'InteractiveSymbol' object does not support item assignment
```

1) How do I assign the 'x_mod' column and then save to disk?
I'm working with large databases: Calculating the column in memory should be fine, but there's no way I can load the entire `ctable` in memory.

2) On a related matter, the `apply` doesn't work for me either. Am I doing something wrong?

```
#This doesn't work:
bl.compute(test_table['x'].apply(f, dshape='int64'))

#This I think should be equivalent, but does work:
bl.compute(test_table['x']*3)
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the transform method in Blaze like this:

```
bz.transform(df, sepal_ratio = df.sepal_length / df.sepal_width   )
```

For other function, you need to use Blaze expression:

```
bz.transform(df, sepal_ratio = BLAZE_symbolic_Expression(df.Col1, df.col2)  )
```

it will add the compute column to the dataframe.
Doc is here:
https://blaze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expressions.html

For example, you can use map:

```
from datetime import datetime
yourexpr = df.col1.map(datetime.utcfromtimestamp)
bz.transform(df, sepal_ratio=yourexpr)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you make this work with a (more or less arbitrary) function `f`? That was the core of my question

Comment: You need to use Blaze expression. Means you need to convert your function into Blaze expression.

Comment: This almost answers the question. Could you post an example or two where a specific function `f` is used to create a new column in `bcolz`? How flexible is the way to define the `f`? I'll accept your answer then, thanks!

Comment: This is in the doc in the  link.  f is depedant of Blaze symbolic expression availability. If missing, you can ask them in their Github..